# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Error loading page for the Firefox SSL

Tags: python, selenium, ssl

```
from selenium import webdriver

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = False
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get('https://cacert.org/')
driver.quit()
```

I tried the above script to handle the SSL, but I get the error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Users/alokv/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2/jre/jre/bin/NIOS_UI_Automation/test_log.py"

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/alokv/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2/jre/jre/bin/NIOS_UI_Automation/test_log.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver.get('https://cacert.org/')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 248, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Error loading page
```

Can anyone please help me by explaining why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it worked fine. I am almost certain that your problem is the website never loads probably due to slow internet. You can insert an `assert "CAcert.org" in driver.title` to make sure that the page is loaded before you continue to whatever is next.

Comment: Thanks for your update, which firefox Version you are using.

Comment: I am using Firefox 47.0 and getting above issue

Comment: Try updating I'm using 51.0.1

Comment: Is it problem with version ??

Comment: It could be. Try updating.

Comment: with the latest version now I am getting a different error "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:certerror?e=nssBadCert&u=https%3A//10.35.6.30/ui/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=10.35.6.30%20uses%20an%20invalid%20security%20certificate.%0A%0AThe%20certificate%20is%20not%20trusted%20because%20it%20is%20self-signed.%0AThe%20certificate%20is%20not%20valid%20for%20the%20name%2010.35.6.30.%0A%0AError%20code%3A%20%3Ca%20id%3D%22errorCode%22%20title%3D%22SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER%22%3ESEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER%3C/a%3E%0A
"

Comment: @Alokkumar that's really strange. I'm sorry I don't really know where to go from here.